# Error output in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber, texpad

I want to use `biblatex`, but I have errors in the output.
I wonder if it's a software problem for typesetting, or maybe the incompatibility of `biber` and `biblatex`.

I'm using TeXpad in Mac OS X.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[spanish,es-noshorthands]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} \addbibresource{biblio}

\begin{document}

\chapter{New Story}

A written line \cite{chopra2001dynamics}.

\printbibliography  

\end{document}
```

And, the bibliography:

```
@book{chopra2001dynamics,
  title={Dynamics of Structures: Theory and Applications to Earthquake Engineering},
  author={Chopra, A.K.},
  isbn={9780130869739},
  lccn={00042751},
  series={Prentice-Hall international series in civil engineering and engineering mechanics},
  year={2001},
  publisher={Prentice Hall}
}

@book{perú2003norma,
  title={Norma Técnica E.030 Diseño Sismorresistente},
  author={Perú and Perú. Ministerio de Vivienda, Construcción y Saneamiento},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Ministerio de Vivienda, Construcción y Saneamiento}
}
```

Comment: You have to use `\cite{chopra2001dynamics}` not `\ref{chopra2001dynamics}`.

Comment: @Guido Sorry, I will change it in the MWE. But that was not the problem, in my document it is correct with `\cite{}`.

Comment: Do not use accented letters  in the key for bibliographic entries. So, do not use `perú2003norma` but `peru2003norma`.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem persists. One error is `Package biblatex Warning: 'babel/polyglossia' detected but 'csquotes' missing.` But I didn't define `polyglossia`.

Comment: You use `babel` and it is recommended to use `csquotes` in such a case, but it is just a warning.

Comment: Yes, only a warning. Another warning is: `LaTeX Warning: Citation 'chopra2001dynamics' on page 3 undefined on input line 265.

[3] [4]

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 271.

[5] (/Users/Isai/Documents/MaestriÃÅa PUCP/IngenieriÃÅa Sismo Resistente/Tarea 3/.texpadtmp/Tarea 3.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                "Tarea 3"
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.`

Comment: You have to specify the full file name (with extension) for the bibliography, so it should be `\addbibresources{biblio.bib}`

Comment: Yes. Awesome! It is predefined in Texpad the autocomplete function. Thank you. Could you please copy your response as an answer to mark it?

Comment: It could be that Biber gets the hiccups with the author `Perú. Ministerio de Vivienda, Construcción y Saneamiento`. Amongst others because it contains a coma and many things that could be mistaken for name parts, to be sure, wrap it in curly braces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `biblatex` one should specify the full name for the bibliography in `\addbibresources`. Thus in the MWE it should be `\addbibresources{biblio.bib}`.

In Texpad ensure that the auto sense function is enabled, and Texpad will try to compile the appropriate number of times (also) depending on what files have been modified.

Also, it would be better to avoid non ascii characters in the key for bibliographic entries,  so use `peru2003normas` instead of `perú2003normas`

Comment: biber has no problem with utf8 keys

Comment: @PLK with utf8 keys the MWE works with lualatex and xelatex but not with pdflatex. With pdflatex, when one uses `perú2003norma`, they key is written as `\abx@aux@cite{per\IeC {\'u}2003norma}` in the aux file, and the entry `{per\IeC {\'u}2003norma` is not found by biber.

Comment: Yes, biber handles it but pdftex doesn't ... it should depend on the particular character when using inputenc.