# TexPad and Bibliographie - biblatex

Tags: biblatex, texpad

This Question is probably related to that one: [Error output in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311274/error-output-in-biblatex)

I'm just moving to TexPad, because I want to use LaTex also on my iPad Pro. I have a lot of (partly really old) LaTeX Sources and had a few problems with character encodings - these are fixed now and I'm using UTF8.

I have a file that compiled normally as long as I did not use my bibliography. Now I added

```
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}  
\addbibresource{../Bibliographie_mg.bib}
```

...d I'm getting error messages that I do not understand:

[image]

I seems to me as if the bib latex package is missing something. Can anyone give me a hint how to fix this? By the way, besides the error messages the file compiles normally, including the bibliography.

So, here a MWE (sorry for the delay I´m on some business trips frequently and there have not the time to face this problem)...

This structure is the one I use most frequently

```
    \documentclass[11pt, german, a4paper]{article}
%
% Language specific stuff
%
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%
% global stuff
%
\usepackage[official,right]{eurosym}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{times}
%
% Document specific stuff
%
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}  
\addbibresource{../Bibliographie_mg.bib} 
%
\begin{document}
This is a citation\cite{Fawcett2003}

\pagebreak
\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you get the proper `.log` and `.blg` files? What do the errors say exactly? Can you give us an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)?

Comment: Any news here? Without a more detailed error message (`.log` and `.blg`) and the document that causes these errors your question is nearly impossible to answer. The screenshot does not even show which command is undefined.

Comment: @moewe: I just added a MWE. This compiles "normally" but shows the mentioned error messages....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not load `\usepackage{german}` and `\usepackage{babel}` at the same time. (See [here](http://www.mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?64991-usepackage-ngerman-vs-usepackage-ngerman-babel), I did not find a better reference, but it came from Ulrike, so it is definitely trustworthy.)

`biblatex` will only pick up your language with `babel`, so you should simply stop loading

```
\usepackage{german}
```

`babel` alone will suffice.

Note that `german` turns on the 'alte Rechtschreibung' and `ngerman` is 'neue Rechtschreibung'.

Comment: Great! Trank you.... Problem solved and learned something :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's a really old post. I'm not sure anyone still encountered the problem.

I had a similar issue on the Texpad macOS. But I found the declaration of the biblatex package is unnecessary.

When I simply deleted the \usepackage{bibletax}, everything worked well.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you tested that? I do not think that is a real solution. Can you show a complete compilable Tex code and its result in an screenshot?

Comment: No one should pay `bibletax` ...