# Biber backend not working in Texpad

Tags: beamer, biber, texpad

This post is similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/143059/usepackagebackend-biberbiblatex-does-not-work-backend-bibtex-works) insofar the biber backend not working (and BibTex backend working). I would like to resolve this problem within the Texpad application, whose settings are determined automatically as in this image:

[image]

The test is very simple, I just use the `fullcite` macro to display a reference within a Beamer presentation. This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \fullcite{Simone2006}
\end{itemize}


\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

and the contents of the `bibliography.bib` file are:

```
%% This BibTeX bibliography file was created using BibDesk.
%% https://bibdesk.sourceforge.io/
%% Saved with string encoding Unicode (UTF-8) 

@article{Simone2006,
    Abstract = {Abstract We present a Generalized Finite Element Method for the analysis of polycrystals with explicit treatment of grain boundaries. Grain boundaries and junctions, understood as loci of possible displacement discontinuity, are inserted into finite elements by exploiting the partition of unity property of finite element shape functions. Consequently, the finite element mesh does not need to conform to the polycrystal topology. The formulation is outlined and a numerical example is presented to demonstrate the potential and accuracy of the approach. The proposed methodology can also be used for branched and intersecting cohesive cracks, and comparisons are made to a related approach (Int. J. Numer. Meth. Engng. 2000; 48:1741). Copyright {\copyright} 2006 John Wiley \& Sons, Ltd.},
    Author = {Simone, A. and Duarte, C. A. and Van der Giessen, E.},
    Date-Added = {2018-06-04 14:13:23 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2020-03-12 09:13:45 +0100},
    Doi = {10.1002/nme.1658},
    Journal = {Int J Numer Meth Eng},
    Keywords = {Generalized Finite Element Method, eXtended Finite Element Method, partition of unity, grain boundary sliding, polycrystals},
    Number = {8},
    Pages = {1122-1145},
    Title = {A Generalized Finite Element Method for polycrystals with discontinuous grain boundaries},
    Volume = {67},
    Year = {2006},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/nme.1658},
    Bdsk-Url-2 = {https://doi.org/10.1002/nme.1658}}
```

This code doesn't work, as references are not crated:
[image]

The error I get is

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Simone2006' on page 1 undefined on input line 17.

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (/Users/aaragon/Desktop/biblio/.texpadtmp/test.vrb)

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 3.

[2] (/Users/aaragon/Desktop/biblio/.texpadtmp/test.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                test
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Is there anything special I need to do in the configuration to make this work (perhaps a script)? Is there any advantage on using the biber backend as opposed to BibTex?

Comment: If I had to guess (and I do) I would say the problem is probably related to the last point mentioned in the configuration summary "Store intermediate files in `.texpadtmp`" Usually temp/build directories like this cause more trouble than they are worth, because they make it hard for Biber to find the required files. You may want to check out see if it helps to disable that option. (`biblatex` and Biber are not mentioned in the list in https://www.texpad.com/support/macos/typesetting/hide-intermediate-files ...)

Comment: Can you obtain the `.blg` file and post it here in its entirety. (It may either be located in the same folder as your `.tex` file or in `/Users/aaragon/Desktop/biblio/.texpadtmp/`).

Comment: Just as a data point: Other people have managed to get TeXpad to compile with `backend=biber,`, so it should be possible: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/375391/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/311274/35864. Just to double check and to make sure future visitors also see the link: Have you configured everything as explained in https://www.texpad.com/support/macos/typesetting/typesetting?

Comment: Any news here? Did you try disabling the `.texpadtmp` folder (hide temporary files option)? Could you obtain the `.blg` file of the Biber run?

Comment: I tried and it didn’t work. I’ll try one more time soon. For me the problem was gone after I changed the backend, so I could still have my references compiled in Beamer.

Answer (score 1):

Just further to this, I had a similar problem with Texpad; I found the bibliography wouldn't compile using Biber. What I do with Texpad is rather than autosense, manually select the configuration settings - the one to store intermediate files in .texpadtmp comes from the selection to 'hide intermediate files'...

After reading the above post about disabling .texpadtmp - I unselected that option, and the bibliography compiled perfectly. So it does seem to be something about these temporary files needed to make Biber work - at least for me. Thanks for the info!